# Adding an Index column on my list for the "Modified" column, did not allow me to show more than 5,000 items on the list view

Tags: 2013, administration, list-view-threshold, threshold, indexed-column

I am working on a SharePoint 2013 on-premises farm, and i have a document library which have 5651 documents, and i got this message that the library exceeds the threshold:-

[image]

and when non-admin users access the list view they will get the error:-

[image]

where the list view  is defined to sort the items based on the Modified field, as follow:-

[image]

now i read that to fix this problem (without having to do UN-recommnded approaches such as expanding the threshold from central admin), i can define a index on the list, so i did so inside the current list, where i defined an index on the "Modified" field >> i run a full crawl. but this did not fix the problem. so i read that if i define an index on a list which already exceeds the threshold then sharepoint will not be able to create the index.
so i added a new document library, i define an index of the "Modified" field as follow:-

[image]

i did a full crawl, then i copied the 5650 documents from the old list to the new list. but still end users can not access the new list view. and the only way that seems to work at my end is to sort the items inside the list view using the ID field. so why defining an Index on the "Modified" field is not working at my end?
Thnaks

Comment: Can you confirm that the 'Modified' column is selected to display in the view settings you referenced?

Comment: @DrewPaxton i am not sure if i got your question correctly, but inside the list view's fields i am showing the following 3 fields:- Name,Modified & Modified by..

Comment: I was just ensuring that you had the 'Modified' column in the view. If you didn't, the index on it wouldn't help.

Comment: @DrewPaxton yes i have the "Modified" column in the view,, but still the index does not seem to work if we have more than 5,000 items... any idea?

Comment: My guess would be that the indexing of 'Modified' only contained a small number of unique values, therefore the operational efficiency of that index was low. Do most of the documents have a similar modified date? This would also explain why using 'ID' was more helpful - more unique values.

Comment: @DrewPaxton if we take the Date without the time then yes those document were added in 1 week time (so i have only 7 different date). also i just did a test where i have uploaded 6,000 items in 1 hour, to a test document library but the index on the "modified " field did not work also...